# Slim framework with raintpl

Tags: php, template-engine, slim

I have an existing project which uses [RainTpl3](https://github.com/rainphp/raintpl3) as its template engine. I am trying to port it to Slim framework 2.
**Q1 :** Is there any way to make slim use my `$tpl` object to render its views (via DI or any other similar approach).

I have managed to hack a way to configure create template object within an external function which then should return the content which then slim should echo. Earlier it could not configure the tpl properly so I then configured it in my init file. Now when I use `$tpl->draw('index');` it is saying template index is not found. **Q2:** Why it can't find the template ?

: *MY_APP_ROOT_/Public/index.php*

```
require_once "../init.php";

# Fire up an app
$app = new Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function(){echo MyNS\Router\APIDefault::showHome();});

$app->get('/Hello', function() {
    echo "Get Route is working.";
});
# Run the Slim application
$app->run();
```

*: MY_APP_ROOT_/Routes/APIDefault.php*

```
<?php
namespace MyNS\Router; 


class APIDefault
{

    private function __construct( $argument)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Error Constructor not allowed", 1);

    }


    public static function showHome()
    {

        $tpl = new \Rain\Tpl();

         $tpl->assign('Name','Abhinav');
        $a = $tpl->draw('index',$return_string = true);
        return $a;
    }
}
```

index.tpl is stored in MY_APP_ROOT_/Templates/ .

Answer (score 0):

1. You could make your own View Script which wraps that Template Engine. Also Slim did this for Twig and Smarty [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views) (only Slim 2).
2. It looks like you never set a directory where to search for templates, am I wrong? But if you go with your own View Plugin you could take this as param in Constructor or something.

Comment: I have set the templates directory in init.php file which is basically a bootloader kind of thing. I will check if I can create the view script. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Not yet.  I spend around 2 days with it.  Then I went old school.  I create `$tpl` object in each of slim's router function and do the processing. RainTPL's draw function has an option `$return_string = true` which returns string instead of forwarding to browser. I echoed that return string as slim app. That works smoothly.